# Best Android practice for referencing a .jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

Consider the situation with an Android library project **A**, which depends on a file **B.jar**.

Now I want to setup an Eclipse development environment as well as a command line environment. 
What is the best approach? Should I:

1. reference the **B.jar** file directly from Eclipse (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries)? But how can I make this to work in the command line environment?
2. create an Android library project using `android create lib-project` consisting of only **B.jar** (if that is possible) and reference this wrapper project using `android update project --path A --library B`? Further use Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries to make the reference in Eclipse.
3. from Eclipse create an Android project and only add **B.jar** to it (I am not sure how). How do I make this work in the command line environment?

Further creating a library project, which depends on other .jar files, should this be distributed as individual .jar files or one single .jar file containing the others?

Answer (score 3):

> reference the B.jar file directly from Eclipse (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries)?

Absolutely not, as that does not work for Eclipse, let alone command-line. While you will compile, your app will not ship the contents of the JAR, and you will crash at runtime.

> create an Android library project using android create lib-project consisting of only B.jar (if that is possible) and reference this wrapper project using android update project --path A --library B?

Um, you could, though that would seem to be overkill.

> from Eclipse create an Android project and only add B.jar to it (I am not sure how)

Put the JAR in the `libs/` directory of the project.

> How do I make this work in the command line environment?

Put the JAR in the `libs/` directory of the project. The `libs/` directory is added to the compile path for both Eclipse and command-line builds, and the contents of `libs/` is added to your Android APK.